# MySQL select from table with ONE row

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table with only one row.

This table is being queried very often. (on every page load).

What is the best way to build query?

Lets assume, this is a table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `counter` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `point1` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `point2` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `point3` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `...` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pointN` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
```

I added `id` field intentionally. The table engine is `MyISAM`.

Right now i'm doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM counter WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

Can i just do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM counter;
```

Or this way:

```
SELECT * FROM counter LIMIT 1;
```

Will there be a difference in performance?

`id` field is not indexed. I don't see the point in index if there is only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer probably optimizes all queries to the same. But theoretically

```
SELECT * FROM counter;
```

is the fastest since it does not need any lookup on the data since there is no `where` clause to limit the data.

Comment: So the `id` field is redundant?

Comment: If you don't need that field it is useless.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using that row very often don't fire an query every time just fire once ans store values locally.

Select all the values at once

```
SELECT * FROM counter;
```

This query is going to be the fastest because there is no condition to check like limit and where.

Comment: @rinchik which language are you using apply a listener or database  trigger So it will be notifying you..

Comment: @rinchik SO I think php doesn't have listeners right. but you can get them by some customization. Search on google. How to apply listener on database tables in php.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM counter;`

This is the fastest, but with this type of table the performance is negligible at best.

Comment: What type of table would you suggest?

Comment: What you are doing now is the best approach, the other apporach would be using arrays but using tables is far more extensible, and easier to work with.